# Detect an application runs by user click or Windows startup in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a C# WinForm application. Currently it runs from a desktop shortcut. But I would like to add it in system startup. User can decide whether it will run on startup or not.

If it runs on system startup, I would like to minimize it on system tray, otherwise it will run on task-bar.

Is there any way to check whether it is being launched on startup or not?

Comment: You can pass argument when you run from startup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your application wont be able to detect (by itself) it was launched at startup or by normal user launching. However you can pass `arguments` to your application and then have your application respond correctly. Here is a basic example

First start in `program.cs` `main` method. Now by default you dont see the startup arguments passed in. However adding the parameter `string[] args` to the `main()` method will expose the command arguments. Such as

```
static class Program
{
    public static bool LaunchedViaStartup { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.LaunchedViaStartup = args != null && args.Any(arg => arg.Equals("startup", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Now the code is simple, we set a static variable to the `Program` class called `LaunchedViaStartup` then before the program starts our main form we check if the command arguments contains our special `startup` argument (via Linq). The name for this argument is simply up to you.

Now in our main form (yes basic) we have access to this property for the lifetime of the application.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("Lanched Via Startup Arg:{0}", Program.LaunchedViaStartup));
    }
}
```

Finally to test this you can simple open the Project Properties window and set the `Command line arguments` similar to the screenshot below.

[image]

Finally to test the Startup argument outside of visual studio add the startup argument to your shortcut, such as the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This is really a nice cooperation. I'm gonna try it. Thank you & +1.

Comment: Your welcome, should provide enough info to get started. Cheers

Comment: Just for curiosity, if the application does not have any shortcut, in that case, is there any way to pass the arguement?

Comment: You can as normal command line based arguments as you would in `cmd` or via the startup registry key as this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778419/how-can-i-pass-argument-for-my-startup-application-in-registry-run-key

Answer (score 2):

Send commend line arguments when you run from start up (define it in shortcut path).

Get the arguments in your application `main` and take decision based on the arguments. Now, It's up to you how you achieve it.

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)

[Here it is for WinForm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288913/How-to-receive-execution-arguments-on-a-Csharp-Win)